# A limit that seems easy but I don't know how to formalize the answer

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

What is the limit as $n$ approaches infinity of $$\Big((n+1)*(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-n*n^{\frac{1}{n}}\Big)^{\frac{n}{ln(n)}}$$
First of all we are in the $1^\infty$ case. So when we have $(x_n)^{y_n}$ where $x_n$ approaches $1$ and $y_n$ approaches $\infty$. Therefore we can rewrite $$(x_n)^{y_n}=\Bigl(\Big(1+(x_n-1)\Big)^{\frac{1}{x_n-1}}\Bigl)^{(x_n-1)y_n}$$ $x_n-1$ approaches 0 therefore $(1+(x_n-1))^{\frac{1}{x_n-1}}$ approaches $e$ so we are left with the limit $(x_n-1)y_n$ which is much easier to compute.
In our case the exponent becomes $$\frac{n}{ln(n)}\Big(\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1}{\frac{1}{n+1}}-\frac{n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}\Big)$$
However $\frac{n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$ is very similar to $ln(n)$ since $$ln(n)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{n^h-1}{h}$$
We can rewrite our previous exponent as $$\frac{n}{ln(n)}\Big(\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1}{\frac{1}{n+1}}-\frac{n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}\Big)=\frac{n}{ln(n)}(a_{n+1}ln(n+1)-a_nln(n))$$ where $$a_n=\frac{e^{\frac{ln(n)}{n}}-1}{\frac{ln(n)}{n}}$$
I have tried to use wolfram alpha for this one and it gives the answer $0$, but there are no step by step solutions. If that limit is $0$ then my original limit would be $e^0=1$. Is there a way I can prove the exponent approaches 0? Or to prove that $n(a_{n+1}ln(n+1)-a_nln(n))$ is bounded? Because that would also imply that the limit is $0$. It is clear that $a_n$ approaches $1$, but I can't take the limit on one term of a product and not the other one so how could i formalize that the limit of $n(a_{n+1}ln(n+1)-a_nln(n))$ is almost equal to $ln\Big((1+\frac{1}{n})\Big)^{n}$ which is $0$?

Answer (score 1):

We can use L'Hôpital's rule. Notice that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \frac{e^0 - 1}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$ since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n} = 0$. So we can apply L'Hôpital's rule.$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}-1}{\frac{\ln n}{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{\ln n }{n}\right)e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}}{\frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{\ln n }{n}\right)} = \lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\frac{\ln n }{n}} = e^0 = 1.$$

Then the exponent limit becomes $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\ln n} (\ln(n+1) - \ln(n)) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(1  + \frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{\ln n}{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}} \cdot \frac{-1}{n^2}}{\frac{1 - \ln n}{n^2}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{n}{n+1}}{\ln n - 1} = 0.$$

The reason we can apply the limit to the $a_n$ first is because they evaluate to $1$ so it doesn't affect the limit. The only way it would be an issue is if the limit was zero or infinity in which case we could not do this.

Comment: I agree that the limit of $a_n$ is 1. But how can I prove that fact that $a_n$ doesn't affect the limit. In my textbook it says that the limit of a product (sum) is the product(sum) of the limits if they exist(excluding $0/0$ or $0*\infty$ or other undetermined cases). Since $n/ln(n)$ approaches $\infty$ and $a_{n+1}ln(n+1)-a_nln(n)$ is $\infty-\infty$ and I would get $\infty(\infty-\infty)$. How can I formalize that $a_{n+1}ln(n+1)-a_nln(n)$ approaches $ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$ which approaches $0$ when $a_n$ approaches $1$. Like is it rigurous to take the limit of one term and not the other?

Comment: Well since $a_n$ approaches 1 then $a_{n+1} \ln(n+1) - a_n\ln(n) = \ln\left(\frac{(n+1)^{a_{n+1}}}{n^{a_n}}\right)$ approaches $\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})$.

Comment: And this is fine because the limit can be taken into the logarithm since it is a nondecreasing function and you have a case of $\infty^1$ in the numerator and denominator which is still okay because this is just infinity. Moreover, by the quotient rule for limits, since the limit in the denominator is nonzero, we can take the quotient of limits after which we have to simplify or use LH because we have a $\infty/\infty$ case.